# PyQIS add values to QGIS qml style file

Tags: pyqgis, style, qgis-2.8, qml

I wonder if it is possible to add new styles to a QGIS style qml file with categorized values programmatically.

I have for example a large qml style file and want to add a new definition for polygons to the existing file. The style of the polygons should be defined with a color and border color.

Is this with pyQGIS possible or are there any tutorials?

Comment: There's a decent blog which describes using [Symbology of Vector Layers in QGIS Python Plugins](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) which I found quite useful, just incase you haven't already seen this. I'm not sure how to add new styles via PyQGIS, but I would probably just edit the .qml style, copy/paste the properties of one symbology and change the values.

Comment: Thank you @Joseph ! I didn't know this blog  but it has a very good explanation of the QGIS symbologie. I would like to avoid to copy/paste stuff in this .qml, that's why I was looking if there are probably other methods of PyGIS. But this blog helps a lot to understand it :)